# Laurent Series for $\frac{1}{1 - z}$ and $\frac{1}{(1 - z)^2}$ around $|z| > 1$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series, taylor-expansion, laurent-series

I am supposed to find the Laurent series for $f(z) = \frac{1}{1 - z}$ and $ f(z) = \frac{1}{(1 - z)^2}$ around $|z| > 1$. I think I can find the first one, but the second one to me seems a little bit confusing.

For the first, one since we want a Laurent series that converges for $|z| > 1$, i.e. $|1/z| < 1$, then we can write the given function as
\begin{equation*}
f(z) = -\dfrac{1}{z}\dfrac{1}{1 - \frac{1}{z}} = -\dfrac{1}{z} \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \left(\dfrac{1}{z}\right)^n = -\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \left(\dfrac{1}{z}\right)^{n + 1}
\end{equation*}
which is the desired series that will converge for $|z| > 1$.

Now for the second one, I know that I can write the function as
\begin{equation*}
f(z) = \dfrac{1}{z^2}\dfrac{1}{\left(1 - \frac{1}{z}\right)^2}
\end{equation*}
But I am not sure how I would be able to expand $\frac{1}{\left(1 - \frac{1}{z}\right)^2}$ as a series. I am not sure if it would follow from the first expansion, or not.

Some help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides the nice answer from @eyeballfrog you can also directly obtain the Laurent series by applying a *[binomial series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)* admissible for $\left|\frac{1}{z}\right|<1$.

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \frac{1}{z^2}\frac{1}{\left(1 - \frac{1}{z}\right)^2}
> &=\frac{1}{z^2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{-2}{n}\left(-\frac{1}{z}\right)^n\\
> &=\frac{1}{z^2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n+1)\frac{1}{z^n}\tag{1}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{n=2}^\infty(n-1)\frac{1}{z^{n}}}\tag{2}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use the binomial identity $\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q$.
- In (2) we shift the index by $2$ to get an expansion in terms of $\frac{1}{z^n}$.

Answer (score 3):

A simple way to do this is to note that $1/(1-z)^2 = d/dz[1/(1-z)]$. Apply this to the Laurent series you found for $1/(1-z)$.